# Postgres delete query - Syntax error near count(*)

Tags: postgresql, join

I want to delete records from F table which has only one H record and that record has thrown 76 errorkode.

I am getting syntax error as i am joining and doing the count(*) check . Is there any correct way to do it???

```
 delete from F fb where id in(select h.id from H h
     join MI m on h.m_i_id=m.id
 join ERROR e on e.m_i_id=m.id
 join ERRORKODE ek on e.errorkode_id=ek.id where errorkode=76) and
     select count(*) from H h where h.f_id = fb.id) =1
```

Comment: The second `and` condition `and select count(*) from H h where h.f_id = fb.id) =1` makes no sense. Did you forget a parentheses? e.g. `and (select count(*) from H h where h.f_id = fb.id) =1`

Comment: Tip of the day: There is no need to alias the table H as h. Since you are not double quoting (YEA) Postgres is case insensitive to object (tables, columns, etc) names, thus H and h are the same.

Comment: @Belayer it was probably caused by anonymization (some comment with real table names was later deleted by OP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `where` clause of `delete` has two conditions separated by `and`, the second one is query which should be in parenthesis. There is missing left parenthesis (before `select` keyword).

Comment: If it was the cause, accept answer to mark question as solved. Also I recommend to keep SQL formatted. There is no single recommended way but choose one and keep it consistently.

Comment: The parenthesis solved the syntax error....but I want to optimize the query like if the count is 1 for my 2nd condition then only it shud go for the 1st condition....here I want to remove the case where 1st condtn is happening for all rows. @Tomas

Comment: That's different question, you are welcome to post another SO question, also there is more convenient environment in question editor to explain what you want to achieve, than in comment. (I would personally expect clarification of difference between `H.id` and `H.fb_id` which are both used to join `H` and `F` tables. Perhaps left join in inner select would be solution for you but it's just a guess. Put an effort to well expressed question and I believe you will get the answer you look for.)

Comment: h is alias of H table....fb alias of F table...fb_id  is a column name...Ya for question thing I need to really go through manuals to make it more readable and expressive